# How to implement search engine in a asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement search engine in my asp.net page. Means I want to keep one textbox and a search button. So what ever the keyword I will enter in that, it will search on this, the way it is happening in google.

Please give some idea.....

Thanks.

Comment: What is your data source ? A database ? A file system ? A file ?

Answer (score 1):

I have pretty good expirience with [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), and you can also use MS SQL server [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) if your data is in a MS SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a great link to get you started on the HTML side. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<form>
Search: <input type="text" name="query" />
</form>
```

As for the ASP side, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp

Comment: Can you please clarify on this? Actually I need the way it is coming on google when you will search anything....

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you trying to find a way for the query to persist across searches?

Comment: See if we are writing anything on google search, then it is giving that search related urls. In the similar way I want to use in my website... It's a kind search engine only.

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on your goals.  Writing a custom search engine for your site sounds like a lofty goal.  Here's some help if you're trying to add Google site-specific search.  http://www.google.com/cse/